# How do I make OpenVPN reconnect when underlying connection is lost on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN on flaky wifi connection and it sometimes loses the link. Is it possible to set it up in some kind of "best effort" mode that just tries to reconnect every second or so if the connection is not up?

I've seen some scripts for Ubuntu, but I'm on windows :(

**Update:** The problem is actually with routing. The VPN does *not* disconnect.

The VPN is supposed to route traffic to `example.com` through VPN and everything else through normal connection. If I start `ping example.com -t` I get `Pinging 10.0.30.51` (i.e. internal VPN IP). I tested, that if I were to disconnect the ping would fail. But I don't disconnect, but rather start new ping with `ping example.com -t`. But alas! Now I get `Pinging 85.78.13.15` (i.e. the internet IP). The system stopped routing the traffic to the domain through the VPN. That seems to be the core issue, but how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide your current client config. You may omit the remote and any embedded certificates/passwords, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
   keepalive 5 15
```

to your config

Comment: For me on Linux, it restarts but cannot reestablish a connection successfully, and keeps looping.

Comment: What is it loggin in that case?